# Sharepoint - Workflow Won't Kick off from another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

In Sharepoint 2013 - I have 2 lists with 2 workflows.

List 1 has a workflow that creates a simple list item in List 2. List 2 has a workflow that then creates a new list item back in the first list.

On both lists, the workflow starts automatically when an item is created.

On List 2, the workflow starts with no issue when List 1's workflow creates the item to List 2. However, when the new item is created on List 1 from List 2, the workflow on List 1 does not start.

I have confirmed that all list items are being created by me, the admin, and not System Account.

These 2 workflows are Sharepoint 2010 workflows. Our farm does not have Sharepoint 2013 workflows enabled.

I do not have access to make any system changes to the farm. I am merely a Site Collection Admin for my sites.

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same result in my local farm, while this would be internal logic for recursion prevention just like SharePoint 2013 workflow.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/19/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-1/

If you can't use SharePoint 2013 workflow, try to use event receiver, and add logic to prevent Infinite loop. [one demo for your reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/)